# can I pull array elements from mongodb to javascript?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I use flask to connect mongodb I have database like this...

{ "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c593b450afcfbde43d9584"
    },

"Sen": "it's wrong",

"words": [
        "it",
        "is",
        "wrong",
        "help"
    ]
}

I want to pass "words" to console log in javascript

in test.py

```
@app.route('/test1')
def test():
user = mongo.db.all
data = user.find_one({},{ "_id": 0 , "words":1})
return render_template('test.html', data = data)
```

in my javascript (test.html)

```
<script language="javascript">
            var Data = "{{data}}";
            console.log(Data);
            console.log(Data.length);
</script>
```

**I want it show me** 
[ "it", "is", "wrong", "help" ]

**but I got** 
{'words': ['it', 'is', 'wrong', 'help']}

and I found something in mlab it's "-" but in js it's '-'

Is it about systax? so how to slove it?

Comment: return render_template('test.html', data=data.words)

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
import json
...
data = user.find_one({},{ "_id": 0 , "words":1})
decoded_data = json.loads(data)
return render_template('test.html', data = decoded_data)
```

Then in javascript you can access `console.log(Data.words);`